# Is it possible to use AirPlay on a MacBook Pro 2013 with the lid closed?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, airplay

Is it possible to send the audio/video to a 3rd generation AppleTV and close the lid on the MacBook? When I try it, the MacBook goes to sleep. Is there any trick to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent your MacBook from going to sleep with [NoSleep](https://code.google.com/p/macosx-nosleep-extension/).

Comment: Does NoSleep also keep the display on? What I want is to close the lid, turn the display off but have AirPlay still running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is turn the Light of the Screen down and use nosleep (or just disable Screensaver and Energysave mode).

On Macs closing the Lid does a hardware Trigger to get your mac to sleep. Don't mess with this because when the Lid is closed the Air-Slices at the Back are covered.

I know one can do this on Windows/Linux Notebooks but you shouldn't do it there either cause they will also overheat.

Comment: Fair enough, the lid cannot be closed. As the next best, is it possible to turn the display off while streaming over AirPlay?

Comment: Kinda you can turn the brightness all the way down, if this is still to bright you could try to cover the display with a dark (black/brown).

Comment: when you turn the brightness all the way down, the display backlight turns off. The only thing that would still possibly be lit is the keyboard backlight which can also be turned all the way down.

Comment: Overheating is not an issue when the MacBook is closed. It is constructed to be used in a closed fashion, it only sleeps with a closed lid when there is no external monitor and input device connected.

Comment: @Kevin let me tell you overheating is really a problem my last two Laptops got a bend/blow up keyboard cause i used them closed. please have a look at the back of your macbook wen you open/close the lid you will see that the lid covers about 80% of the heat-exhaust slices - thats why you shouldn't force a macbook to run with a closed lid. i think the best  would ether be to use a real Server, NAS or a Mac Mini to stream.

Comment: Apple officially supports running them closed. Also, the MacBook has multiple temperature sensors, and it would turn off if it gets to hot.

Answer (score 1):

Overheating (as some people say) is not an issue when the MacBook is closed. It is constructed to also be used in a closed fashion, it only sleeps with a closed lid when there is no external monitor and input device connected as Apple notes in their knowledge-base article:

[Mac notebooks: How to use your computer in closed clamshell (display closed) mode with an external display](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3131?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

There are several free tools that keep the mac awake when closed. I use [InsomniaX](http://semaja2.net/insomniaxinfo)